# How to capture all the values from Auto Suggest Edit Box and display it in console?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I tried to capture all the values from the Auto Suggest Edit box like Google Search edit box, I have tried this code but didnt worked for me. Everything looks good but 
it is showing some error with list

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://google.co.in");

driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("Facebook");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS);

List <WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody"));

for (int i = 0; i<lst.size(); i++)
{
   System.out.println(lst.get(i).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
List <WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span"));
```